# Pandas Dataframe Filtering

Tags: python, pandas

given a dataframe with two columns: User and Code, how can I filter out the user entries where they don't have at least x entries with a given Code?

E.g. I'd like to filter out all users when they don't have at least 5 occurances of a given type:

```
User    Type
A       Alpha
A       Alpha
A       Alpha
A       Alpha
A       Alpha
A       Beta
A       Beta
A       Beta
B       Alpha
B       Alpha
B       Alpha
B       Alpha
B       Alpha
```

Here I would like to filter out(remove) the 4x A with the Beta code (only 4 times here), while keeping everything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` on 'User' and 'Type' and `filter`:

```
In [91]:
df.groupby(['User', 'Type']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 4)

Out[91]:
   User   Type
0     A  Alpha
1     A  Alpha
2     A  Alpha
3     A  Alpha
4     A  Alpha
8     B  Alpha
9     B  Alpha
10    B  Alpha
11    B  Alpha
12    B  Alpha
```

Comment: this is perfect indeed! Thanks so much! I tried altering the labnda function so that it does one more step - filters out all the records where the sum of another field is smaller than 10.
arr.groupby(['User','TYPE', 'APPDOMAIN']).filter(lambda x: sum(arr.Closed) > 10)
Didn't quite do it though. Any last advice? Thanks again so much!

Comment: the lambda is passed the group as `x`, so it should be `(...).filter(lambda x : sum(x.Closed)) > 10` instead of `... arr.Closed ...`

Answer (score 1):

> how can I filter out the user entries where they don't have at least x entries with a given Code?

If you want to know which ones were kept or removed:

```
# counts
grouped = df.groupby(['User', 'Type']).apply(lambda g : len(g) > 4) 
grouped = grouped.reset_index(name='keep')
# merge back and filter
data = df.merge(grouped).query('keep == True')
removed = df.merge(grouped).query('keep == False')
```